# Math Operations in App Inventor 2

Tags: android, app-inventor

Does anyone know any block in App Inventor 2 that acts like parentheses which will allow the computer to do those calculations first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this depends on how you are nesting the blocks

the first example calculates (2+3) x 4 = 20
the second example calculates 2 + (3 x 4) = 14

[image]