# App Inventor - Mathematical Formula

Tags: android, app-inventor

I'm having some issues using the following formula in App Inventor:

> (d + m + y + (y / 4) + c)modulo 7

I would like to ask if anyone knows how I would layout such a formula using the blocks in App Inventor?

This is what I've tried:
[image]

Comment: What is the problem you are facing

Comment: @war_Hero how would I do that formula using the 'Math' blocks in app inventor

Comment: so what have you tried? just put the blocks together.... in case you have doubts, you might want to show us a screenshot of your `relevant` blocks...see also my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26041125/1545993

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/26041125/1545993

Comment: @Taifun I've tried this, http://prntscr.com/acgq9b . And no, not a duplicate.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The nesting of your blocks is correct, [see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26041125/1545993), you only have some problems with the `modulo` block and you forgot an `y`, see also the [documentation about modulo](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/math.html#modulo):

> **modulo**
>   Modulo(a,b) is the same as remainder(a,b) when a and b are positive.
>   More generally, modulo(a,b) is defined for any a and b so that
>   (floor(a/b)× b) + modulo(a,b) = a. For example, modulo(11, 5) = 1,
>   modulo(-11, 5) = 4, modulo(11, -5) = -4, modulo(-11, -5) = -1.
>   Modulo(a,b) always has the same sign as b, while remainder(a,b) always
>   has the same sign as a.

[image]

Also use **Do it** to debug your blocks!

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you are doing hete is: 
`(d + m + y + (y / 4) + c)*modulo (7, 1)` 
You should move everything before the modulo to the first slot in the modulo and write 7 in the second slot

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can solve that formula.

[image]

Where were yo wrong:

You took the whole equation and multiplied it with 7 modulo 1 which is zero. Thing you need is the value of the equation with modulo 7 i.e (value of equation) and the reminder of the value divided by 7.

You can add spacs for more blocks in addition from that gear icon, as you have added so many addition blocks, this would help you to save the time.

[image]